# Google play game service: how to get information about the apps authorized (played) by my friends

Tags: google-plus

I'm developing an android game and I wish to add leader board and friend invitation features using Google play game service. I query the list of friends using Plus Client.load-people function. However how can I know which friends are already playing my game (and so should be displayed in the leader board), and which friend are not (and so can be invited)? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To make the player's score appear in the leaderboard you call GamesClient.submitScore. The Google backend decides which scores to display in "my circles" and "public" based on options selected by the user when they first sign in.

I think Google expect developers to allow users to manually invite their friends rather than us programmatically spamming circles ( I'm not saying that it is not possible to do this, but you will probably hit the api call limit and/or upset people if you make a success of this !).

Comment: Thanks. So you think that if I query a list of friends (depending on the options I selected when signing in), I will have no way (or no expected way) to know which of these friends are playing the game, and what is their score/ranking in the leaderboard?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this - for example check out this api call :https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore.html#getScoreHolder()  but I suspect that when you try to do it you may get "not authorised" and  is there a way of translating a display name to a google id ? Furthermore, I know of no current method for finding out who is playing your game - but you should check the api reference to confirm this.